# I need to add the single post template to this php snippet

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I am trying to get the intro text area to show on single posts, however, I can't quite figure out how to get it to work.

```
    if( ! function_exists( 'ctsi_intro_text' ) ) :
add_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'ctsi_intro_text', 5 );
function ctsi_intro_text() {
    if( ( ! is_page() || is_front_page() ) && ! is_home()  ) return;
    if( ( is_page() && get_field( 'ctsi_intro_text' ) ) || ( is_home() && get_field( 'ctsi_intro_text', get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) ) ) :
?>
    <div class="intro-text">
        <div class="wrap">
            <?php if( is_page() || is_single() ) : ?>
                <?php echo get_field( 'ctsi_intro_text' ) ? get_field( 'ctsi_intro_text' ) : ''; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php echo get_field( 'ctsi_intro_text', get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) ? get_field( 'ctsi_intro_text', get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) : ''; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Genesis is an excellent framework but certain parts of the documentation can be a little lacking. If you want to customise your single post template, you can do the following

Create a file in your child theme folder called single.php Make sure the last line in this file is the following:

```
enter code here
```

genesis();

Use the Genesis theme hooks and filters to manipulate your markup. The visual theme hook guide is an excellent resource for this. See: https://genesistutorials.com/visual-hook-guide/

So, if you wanted to modify the entry content, you could do something like this:

```
remove_action('genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content');
add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'custom_entry_content' ); // Add custom loop

function custom_entry_content() {
    //Custom Entry Content
}
```

Hope this help.